# Should "else" be used in situations where control flow renders it redundant?

Tags: programming-practices, conditions, control-flow

I sometimes stumble upon code similar to the following example (what this function does exactly is out of the scope of this question):

```
function doSomething(value) {
  if (check1(value)) {
    return -1;
  }
  else if (check2(value)) {
    return value;
  }
  else {
    return false;
  }
}
```

As you can see, `if`, `else if` and `else` statements are used in conjunction with the `return` statement. This seems fairly intuitive to a casual observer, but I think it would be more elegant (from the perspective of a software developer) to drop the `else`-s and simplify the code like this:

```
function doSomething(value) {
  if (check1(value)) {
    return -1;
  }
  if (check2(value)) {
    return value;
  }
  return false;
}
```

This makes sense, as everything that follows a `return` statement (in the same scope) will never be executed, making the code above semantically equal to the first example.

Which of the above fits the good coding practices more? Are there any drawbacks to either method with regard to code readability?

*Edit: A duplicate suggestion has been made with [this question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/122485/elegant-ways-to-handle-ifif-else-else) provided as reference. I believe my question touches on a different topic, as I am not asking about avoiding duplicate statements as presented in the other question. Both questions seek to reduce repetitions, albeit in slightly different ways.*

Comment: The `else` is a lesser issue, the bigger problem is you are obviously returning two data types out of a single function, which makes the API of the function unpredictable.

Comment: E_CLEARLY_NOTADUPE

Comment: @DavidPacker: At least two; could be three. `-1` is a number, `false` is a boolean, and `value` isn't specified here so it could be any type of object.

Comment: @Yay295 I was hoping the `value` is actually an integer. If it can be anything then that's even worse.

Comment: @DavidPacker This is a very important point, especially when raised with regard to a question about good practices. I agree with you and Yay295, however the code samples serve as an example to demonstrate an unrelated technique of coding. Nevertheless, I keep in mind that this is an important matter and shouldn't be overlooked in actual code.

Comment: The first approach is amenable to a ternary expression, which is even terser and clearer.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I like the one without `else` and here's why:

```
function doSomething(value) {
  //if (check1(value)) {
  //  return -1;
  //}
  if (check2(value)) {
    return value;
  }
  return false;
}
```

Because doing that didn't break anything it wasn't supposed to.

Hate interdependence in all it's forms (including naming a function `check2()`).  Isolate all that can be isolated.  Sometimes you need `else` but I don't see that here.

Comment: I generally prefer this also, for the reason stated here.  However, I usually place a comment at the close of each `if` block of `} //else` to make it clear, when reading the code, that the only intended execution after the `if` code block is if the condition in the `if` statement was false. Without something like this, particularly if the code within the `if` block grows to be more complex, it may not be clear to whoever is maintaining the code that the intent was to never execute past the `if` block when the `if` condition is true.

Comment: @Makyen you raise a good point.  One I was trying to ignore.  I also believe something should be done after the `if` to make it clear that this section of code is done and the structure is finished.  To do this I do what I haven't done here (because I didn't want to distract from the OP's main point by making other changes). I do the simplest thing I can that achieves all that without being distracting.  I add a blank line.

Answer (score 31):

I think it depends on the semantics of the code. If your three cases are dependent on each other, state it explicitly. This increases readability of the code and makes it easier to understand for anyone else. Example:

```
if (x < 0) {
    return false;
} else if (x > 0) {
    return true;
} else {
    throw new IllegalArgumentException();
}
```

Here you are clearly depending on the value of `x` in all three cases. If you'd omit the last `else`, this would be less clear.

If your cases are not directly depended on each other, omit it:

```
if (x < 0) {
    return false;
}
if (y < 0) {
    return true;
}
return false;
```

It's hard to show this in a simple example without context, but I hope you get my point.

Answer (score 6):

I prefer the second option (separate `ifs` with no `else if` and early `return`) **BUT** that is **as long as the code blocks are short**.

If code blocks are long it's better using `else if`, because otherwhise you would not have a clear understanding of the several exits points the code has.

For example:

```js
function doSomething(value) {
  if (check1(value)) {
    // ...
    // imagine 200 lines of code
    // ...
    return -1;
  }
  if (check2(value)) {
    // ...
    // imagine 150 lines of code
    // ...
    return value;
  }
  return false;
}
```

In that case, it is better use `else if`, store the return code in a variable and have just one return sentence at the end.

```js
function doSomething(value) {
  retVal=0;
  if (check1(value)) {
    // ...
    // imagine 200 lines of code
    // ...
    retVal=-1;
  } else if (check2(value)) {
    // ...
    // imagne 150 lines of code
    retVal=value;
  }
  return retVal;
}
```

But as one should strive for functions to be short, I'd say keep it short and exit early as in your first code snippet.

Comment: I agree with your premise, but as long as we're discussing how code ought to be, might we as well not just agree code blocks should be short anyway? I think it is worse to have a long block of code not broken into functions than to use else if, if I had to choose.

Comment: A curious argument. `return` is within 3 lines of `if` so it's not that different than `else if` even after 200 lines of code.  The [single return style](http://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/118717/131624) you introduce here is a tradition of c and other languages that don't report errors with exceptions.  The point was to create a single place to clean up resources.  Exception languages use a `finally` block for that. I suppose this also creates a place to put a break point if your debugger wont let you put one on the functions closing curly brace.

Comment: I don't like the assignment to `retVal` at all. If you can safely exit a function do so immediately, without assigning the safe value to be returned to a variable of a single exit from the function. When you use the single return point in a really long function I don't generally trust other programmers and end up looking through the rest of the function for other modifications of the return value as well. Fail fast and return early are, among others, two rules I live by.

Comment: @DavidPacker  I agree with you, my suggestion is only for long blocks.

Comment: In my opinion it's even worse for long blocks. I try to exit functions as early as possible no matter what the outer context is.

Comment: @DavidPacker In the case of short blocks you can see in a glance all what's happening. So you are very concious of early returns. In long blocks (that shouldn't exits by the way)  you have to study the code to know all exit points. My suggestion is more on the line of a code standard for a team: "use early returns if blocks are short, if blocks are long, make them short".

Comment: I'm with DavidPacker here. The single return style forces us to study all assignment points as well as code after assignment points.  Studying the exit points of a early return style would be preferable to me, long or short. So long as the language permits a finally block.

Comment: If there is more code in the if statement blocks than you can easily see and take in on-screen, break it out into functions with very clear names. Then it frankly won't matter whether you set a return value or have multiple exit points. Thousand line long magical procedures are anathema.

Comment: early returns are meant to be _early_ in the function. not half way through

Comment: @CandiedOrange hit the nail on the head when you wrote, "I suppose this also creates a place to put a break point if your debugger wont let you put one on the functions closing curly brace". The main reason I prefer single returns in _any_ language is so I can quickly add logging to a function: rather than adding logging calls before every `return`, it's much easier to add a single logging call just before the final (and only) `return`.

Comment: @kmoser A fair point.  Alternatively, you could push the if structure down into a private function.  Also, you could do your logging with one of the Aspect Oriented Programming solutions.  Logging is something AOP does well.

Comment: @CandiedOrange In theory I would implement an AOP solution; in practice that requires a whole other level of abstraction, not to mention its own set of implementation-specific quirks and bugs (especially when dealing with environments where AOP is an afterthought at best). Sometimes it's just easier to add a quick logging call, run some tests, then remove (or comment out) the call after you've found the bug.

Answer (score 4):

I use both in different circumstances. In a validation check, I omit the else. In a control flow, I use the else.

```
bool doWork(string name) {
  if(name.empty()) {
    return false;
  }

  //...do work
  return true;
}
```

vs

```
bool doWork(int value) {
  if(value % 2 == 0) {
    doWorkWithEvenNumber(value);
  }
  else {
    doWorkWithOddNumber(value);
  }
}
```

The first case reads more like you're checking all the prerequisites first, getting those out of the way, then progressing to the actual code you want to run. As such, the juicy code you really want to be running belongs in the scope of the function directly; it's what the function's really about.
The second case reads more like both paths are valid code to be run that are just as relevant to the function as the other based on some condition. As such, they belong in similar scope levels to each other.

Answer (score 0):

The only situation I've ever seen it really matter is code like this:

```
List<?> toList() {
    if (left != null && right != null) {
        Arrays.asList(merge(left, right));
    }
    if (left != null) {
        return Arrays.asList(left);
    }
    if (right != null) {
        return Arrays.asList(right);
    }
    return Arrays.asList();
}
```

There is clearly something wrong here. The problem is, it's not clear if `return` should be added or `Arrays.asList` removed. You cannot fix this without deeper inspection of related methods. You can avoid this ambiguity by always using fully exhaustive if-else blocks. This:

```
List<?> toList() {
    if (left != null && right != null) {
        Arrays.asList(merge(left, right));
    } else if (left != null) {
        return Arrays.asList(left);
    } else if (right != null) {
        return Arrays.asList(right);
    } else {
        return Arrays.asList();
    }
}
```

won't compile (in statically checked languages) unless you add explicit return in first `if`.

Some languages do not even allow the first style. I try to use it only in strictly imperative context or for preconditions in long methods:

```
List<?> toList() {
    if (left == null || right == null) {
        throw new IllegalStateException()
    }
    // ...
    // long method
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Having three exits from the function like that is really confusing if you are trying to follow the code through and bad practice.

If you have a single exit point for the function then the elses are required.

```
var result;
if(check1(value)
{
    result = -1;
}
else if(check2(value))
{
    result = value;
}
else 
{
    result = 0;
}
return result;
```

In fact lets go even further.

```
var result = 0;
var c1 = check1(value);
var c2 = check2(value);

if(c1)
{
    result = -1;
}
else if(c2)
{
    result = value;
}

return result;
```

Fair enough you could argue for a single early return on input validation. Just avoid wrapping the whole bulk if your logic in an if.

Comment: This style comes from languages with explicit resource management. Single point was needed to free up allocated resources. In languages with automatic resource management single return point is not that important. You should rather focus on reducing number and scope of variables.

Comment: a: no language is specified in the question. b: I think you are wrong on this. there are plenty of good reasons for single return. it reduces complexity and enhances readability

Comment: Sometimes it reduces complexity, sometimes it increases it. See http://wiki.c2.com/?ArrowAntiPattern

Comment: No I think it always reduces cyclomatic complexity, see my second example. check2 _always_ runs

Comment: having the early return is an optimisation which complicates the code by moving some code into a conditional

Comment: Your second example changes the meaning of the program. What if a truthy result from check1 means check2 is invalid?

Comment: its just example code

Answer (score -3):

I prefer omitting the redundant else statement. Whenever I see it (in code review or refactoring) I wonder if the author understood the control flow and that there might be a bug in the code.

If the author believed the else statement was necessary and thus did not understand the control flow implications of the return statement surely such a lack of understanding is a major source of bugs, in this function, and in general.

Comment: While I happen to agree with you this isn't an opinion poll.  Please back up your claims or the voters won't treat you kindly.